# Why does dplyr::case_when() give different output for equivalent logic, unless using rowwise()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I came across a strange behavior when building a logic in `dplyr::case_when()`.

How come the logic `(col_a != col_b) | (col_a != col_c)` works but the equivalent `!col_a %in% c(col_b, col_c)` doesn't, unless we `rowwise()` first?

### Example

**Data**

```r
df_colors <-
  structure(
    list(
      col_a = c(
        NA,
        NA,
        "blue",
        "green",
        "red",
        "green",
        "blue",
        "red",
        "green",
        "red"
      ),
      col_b = c(
        NA,
        NA,
        "green",
        "blue",
        "blue",
        "red",
        NA,
        "orange",
        "orange",
        "blue"
      ),
      col_c = c(NA,
                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "blue", NA, NA, NA)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-10L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

df_colors
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    col_a col_b  col_c
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#>  1 <NA>  <NA>   <NA> 
#>  2 <NA>  <NA>   <NA> 
#>  3 blue  green  <NA> 
#>  4 green blue   <NA> 
#>  5 red   blue   <NA> 
#>  6 green red    <NA> 
#>  7 blue  <NA>   blue 
#>  8 red   orange <NA> 
#>  9 green orange <NA> 
#> 10 red   blue   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**My code**

Two equivalent pieces of code lead to different output.

```r
library(dplyr)

desired_output <-
  df_colors %>%
  mutate(new_col = case_when(if_all(c(col_a, col_b, col_c), is.na) ~ NA_character_,
                             col_a == col_c ~ "col_a equals col_c",
                             col_a == col_b ~ "col_a equals col_b",
                             (col_a != col_b) | (col_a != col_c) ~ "col_a is neither col_b nor col_c" ))



strange_output <-
  df_colors %>%
  mutate(new_col = case_when(if_all(c(col_a, col_b, col_c), is.na) ~ NA_character_,
                             col_a == col_c ~ "col_a equals col_c",
                             col_a == col_b ~ "col_a equals col_b",
                             !col_a %in% c(col_b, col_c) ~ "col_a is neither col_b nor col_c" ))


desired_output
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    col_a col_b  col_c new_col                         
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>                           
#>  1 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>                            
#>  2 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>                            
#>  3 blue  green  <NA>  col_a is neither col_b nor col_c
#>  4 green blue   <NA>  col_a is neither col_b nor col_c
#>  5 red   blue   <NA>  col_a is neither col_b nor col_c
#>  6 green red    <NA>  col_a is neither col_b nor col_c
#>  7 blue  <NA>   blue  col_a equals col_c              
#>  8 red   orange <NA>  col_a is neither col_b nor col_c
#>  9 green orange <NA>  col_a is neither col_b nor col_c
#> 10 red   blue   <NA>  col_a is neither col_b nor col_c

strange_output
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    col_a col_b  col_c new_col           
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>             
#>  1 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>              
#>  2 <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>              
#>  3 blue  green  <NA>  <NA>              
#>  4 green blue   <NA>  <NA>              
#>  5 red   blue   <NA>  <NA>              
#>  6 green red    <NA>  <NA>              
#>  7 blue  <NA>   blue  col_a equals col_c
#>  8 red   orange <NA>  <NA>              
#>  9 green orange <NA>  <NA>              
#> 10 red   blue   <NA>  <NA
```

Only if I use `rowwise()` I get the desired output with the second code.

```r
desired_output_with_rowwise <-
  df_colors %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new_col = case_when(if_all(c(col_a, col_b, col_c), is.na) ~ NA_character_,
                             col_a == col_c ~ "col_a equals col_c",
                             col_a == col_b ~ "col_a equals col_b",
                             !col_a %in% c(col_b, col_c) ~ "col_a is neither col_b nor col_c" ))
```

How come that `!col_a %in% c(col_b, col_c)` isn't giving the same result as `(col_a != col_b) | (col_a != col_c)`, unless I use `rowwise()`?

---

EDIT

---

Aside from wanting to understand why there's such a difference, it's also a performance issue, because using `rowwise()` makes the operation substantially slower to run with large data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a smaller example to understand the issue.

```
a <- c(1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8)
b <- c(2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8)
c <- c(1, 1, 2, 6, 6, 8)
```

We are looking for values where `a` is different than `b` or `c`. So it should return `TRUE` for all the positions except 2 and the last one which is 6th.

```
(a != b) | (a != c)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

This is correct since position 2 and 6 is `FALSE`.

```
!a %in% c(b, c) 
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This looks incorrect.

***Why?***

In the first case we are comparing the values element-wise i.e `a[1]` is compared with `b[1]` and `c[1]`. Similarly, `a[2]` is compared with `b[2]` and `c[2]` and so on. In the second case we are checking `a[1]` with all the values in `b` and `c` . Similarly, we are checking `a[2]` for all the values in `b` and `c`. Only 7 is the value in `a` which is not present at any position in `b` or `c`.

Comment: Thank you! In other words, would you say that `(a != b) | (a != c)` is a vectorized operation whereas `(a != b) | (a != c)` isn't vectorized?

Comment: You mean `!a %in% c(b, c)` in the second case? I don't think I'll say that `!a %in% c(b, c)` isn't vectorised. It works for vectors clearly (`a` is a vector) but we want to check for only subset of `b` and `c` values here and not all of them.

Comment: Yes, I meant `!a %in% c(b, c)` in the second case. Thank you!